# Typescript type with get function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm looking for a way to define a getter for a type object in React.

```
type User= {
  firstName?: string
  lastName: string
  age: number
}
```

In my React components I want to display `firstName` primarily and `lastName` if `firstName` is undefined. This logic also covers assignment e.g. `author= u.firstName ?? u.lastName`.

How can I define a getter than makes sure the logic is used consistently throughout the application? Like:

```
author = u.getName()
```

in code and:

```
{{u.getName()}
```

in templates.

From my research it seems like I should replace the `type` with `class` to be able to declare member functions. Do you know if `type` support member functions?

Comment: It seems worth noting, with your current types, `firstName` can't be undefined. (That would be `firstName?: string`)

Comment: Instead of using classes, you could also define a format function, that accepts anything that might have a first name but at least has a last name and returns the formatted string. This way you could re-use the format function even for types that are not `User`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily define a type that has a function/method:

```js
type User = {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    age: number;
    getFullName(): string;
};
```

But it's just is what it name implies: a type. It doesn't do anything. The tricky part is setting the value:

```js
const u: User = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: 30,
    getFullName() {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to define the `getFullName` method every time, you should probably [use a class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html).

Comment: Perfect! One question: I tried this in  my React component but get error: Functions are not valid as a React child when I try to render the command in a template

Comment: That's because getFullName *is* a function. You should probably use a class then.

Comment: No you were right :) I forgot to use parenthesis to call the function in the template. {u.getFullName()}